# Too long hydro line

Tags: brakes, hydraulic-disc-brake

I've bought a new rear hydraulic disk brake (shimano m355) to replace a broken one. It works fine, but when installing I've noticed that the tube from the lever to the brake is too long for my bike.

Can this be an issue and do I need to shorten it? I does not cause any problem, except (maybe) the look, but I dont really care about it.

Sorry, if I name it (tube, line, or...) incorrectly - don't know the English word for it.

Comment: Without the right tools, you're risking your life by faffing with brakes.  Honestly the safest option is to get your LBS to do it because they will have any flaring and compression tools.  If you do it with some pliers its not going to be a good fitment.

Comment: Of course I won't do it myself. The question is - do I need to bother?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a couple of downsides to overly long hydraulic hoses. The most obvious issue is that you end up with excess tubing that may get snagged if you don't tie it off securely.

Another less obvious issue is that hoses expand slightly as the pressure in the system builds (i.e. when you squeeze the brake lever and apply the brakes). A longer hose means that the overall increase in volume is greater and you end up with slightly less effective brakes. That said, it's usually a minor difference in bicycle brakes so it's not the end of the world if you ignore it.